# LVM Couldn't find device with uuid

Tags: mount, lvm

I got a 12TB and 4TB in a LVM so they look like one 16TB drive.

The 12TB was not getting enough amps. It's a WD external USB 3.0 one. It had a 12 volt 1.5 amp on it for months and I was hearing that sound like it don't have enough power. I have external drives side by side on a shelf so did not know what one was making that sound.

So yesterday while my server was running I unplug the power to each one. Till that sound stop. It was the last one the 12TB.

So I put a 12 volt 4 amp brick type power supply on it.

Then did a `mount -a` and it took a little time but came back with no errors.

Then next day today can't mount it. I get this. It was read only. So I rebooted it now when I do a mount -a I get this:

```
root@rayday:~# mount -a
mount: /media/12+4TB_one_replace_5: special device /dev/12+4GB-one/12+4GB-one does not exist.
root@rayday:~#


root@rayday:~# vgck 12+4GB-one
  WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid 2xhVV4-XbdO-s3iJ-bM0Q-ZNaO-OVjM-h2UmDs.
  WARNING: VG 12+4GB-one is missing PV 2xhVV4-XbdO-s3iJ-bM0Q-ZNaO-OVjM-h2UmDs (last written to /dev/sdd1).
  The volume group is missing 1 physical volumes.
root@rayday:~#
```

It's UUID looks like this now.

```
/dev/sdh1: UUID="55e4b7ae-508f-473b-a70e-8f2154e4ea71" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a7d43d80-01"
```

I don't know why it's UUID changed.

How can I fix this?

-Raymond Day

Answer (score -2):

It was the AC power cable plug in the brick was not pushed in all the way. So the drive stop getting power after I did the mount -a when I 1st plug it in. It must of just barley been plug in the power supply.

-Raymond Day